# Use TortoiseSVN track existing working copy

Tags: tortoisesvn

The repository is 1GB big. I need to checkout the repo to 2 PC. Is it possible to use TortoiseSVN checkout a working copy to first PC, then copy this local copy to 2nd PC. Then use TortoiseSVN track on 2nd PC directly? So I can save some time through checking out the repo again under slow network transferring rate.

Also, how do I start version control the copy on 2nd PC? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works without any problems. Be sure to copy all .svn folders.

Once you copied folder, TortoiseSVN would automagically recognize it and will add menu items in context menu in this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works just fine. in fact, you go bit further and use an app like [Live Sync](http://sync.live.com) to keep the two working copies in sync after the initial copy and both working copies will still work just fine with the SVN repo.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.  You can use any SVN client you want with the checkout copy, not just Tortoise.